# Wordpress: Square monitor completely messes up the look of the site

Tags: css, wordpress

So I'm building a website for a client on the Wordpress platform and he says that when he views it on an old square monitor, the layout is all messed up. I know most monitors nowadays are more widescreen and you'd be pressed to find a smaller, square monitor, but he wants it to look good on every monitor, which I completely understand.

I'm just having a hard time trying to fix it because I'm building it on a widescreen laptop and widescreen monitor so I can't really tell if it's fixed when I make changes.

So my question is, how can I view the changes I've made as a square monitor? I've tried resizing the browser window, but it doesn't make any changes. It's not looking like anything he describes. Also, I know this is a longshot, but are there any WP plugins or anything that will fix it?

P.S. I've been making changes to the style.css file with the @media property. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you could post the URL of the website, so that people who have a 4:3 monitor can better understand the issue.

Comment: If you want to mimic a square display, try running an OS in Virtual Box and installing guest additions. This should allow you to freely resize the virtual screen. Still, resizing the browser window should do the trick anyway. Be sure to ask the client what browser he or she uses. What I mean is that more than just one factor (square monitor) could be the cause of the problem.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong here but I would imagine an ancient old monitor is on a computer running an ancient old browser that doesn't support the @media property.

Comment: It's a website for a client so I don't feel comfortable putting the link out here. I know it's not very helpful but I just can't do it, sorry. I may try a Virtual OS and see if I can imitate the screen. Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Back in the day, websites were always developed to accommodate the "square" monitor resolution.  Today, the number of users using 800x600 or 640x480 is [negligible](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_display.asp) which is why most sites leverage the space benefits introduced by the wider ratio.  And, without getting into the possibility of an antiquated browser to go with his antiquated hardware and why one wouldn't want to pander to either of those over the mass as a whole, I'll stick to the question at hand.

Without seeing the website, I can't say for sure what's going on but I'm willing to guess that one of two things is happening:

1. The way in which the content is organized is causing one area to push into another
2. He has to use the horizontal scroll his on browser to see the whole site.

The solution for overcoming both of those problems is a whole other issue but, to get you both looking at the same page, set your monitor's resolution equal to his to simulate his view.  On both my desktop and laptop, I can set it to 800x600 so I'm willing to be you can too.

Comment: I like this answer (I'm old enough to remember the 'should we start ignoring 640x480' debate) but surely 800x600 and 640x480 are.......not square. We're talking Vic20s and Dragons here!

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thanks for your answer. Now I just have to convince him that the number of users who will use monitors that size aren't worth it to accomodate them.

Comment: @McNab  I'm old enough for that too 640x480 debate as well... and square is not the term I'd used to describe 4:3 but it is important to recognize that everyone is graced with cat-like Tetris skillz.  I, for one, am waiting to hear if he's got IE6 to go along with his square monitor.

Comment: Well he said he looked at it from his work (he works at a university). I guess they don't have the budget for newer monitors :)